Localization in ASP.NET Core Web API
After some searching, I've written the following code in Program.cs:
#region Localization
builder.Services.AddLocalization(option =>
{
    option.ResourcesPath = "Resources";
});

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[] { "en", "ru" };
    options.SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
        .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
});
#endregion

app.UseRequestLocalization();

I'm trying to use localization like this:
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{    private readonly static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    private readonly IStringLocalizer<AuthController> _localizer;

    public AuthController(IStringLocalizer<AuthController> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    [HttpGet("test")]
    public string Test()
    {
        return _localizer["About Title"];
    }
}

I've tried adding ui-culture=ru to the request and setting Accept-Language to ru, but the server still returns "About Title"
I wanted to get an answer in one of the localization languages

Have you created the AuthController.ru.resx resource file?
You didn't mention anything about the resource file.
Because your code seems correct.
